# Questions that ask about the state of X "right now".

Tags: discussion

I have noticed a lot of seemingly valid questions are being closed as being too time localized, such as [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1440/what-is-the-latest-and-most-up-to-date-flight-simulator-out-right-now-closed) one or [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/which-console-has-sold-the-most-units) one.

I agree that in its current form "right now" it can be problematic.  However, I also think that if the question were stated as "As of July 12 2010" it should be answerable.  But this also begs the question, what happens when on July 12 2011 the next generation of flight simulation games comes out?

What do you think?

Comment: http://begthequestion.info/

Comment: Actually, `to beg` means either `to implore` or `to dodge`.  Begging the question, as per the logical fallacy, calls upon the latter meaning.  The word beg, in modern English is derived from beggar, which is in turn derived from the Old English word, `bedecian`, meaning `one who solicits alms from the wealthy as a mode of living`.  While the literal meaning of the phrase is proscribed, the modern age is awash with contextual change.  Language is mutable, and this mutability is not constrained to tribal tongues (consider the generational change in American Standard English in the past century).

Comment: Unfortunately, 600 characters is not long enough for a real argument, and I am pulling this all out of my @ss. :D

Comment: Limiting it to "July 12, 2010" is *still* too localized - it's still confined within a specific point in time. In fact, for a "right now" question asked on July 12, it's completely identical.

Comment: @Mechko, you are going to have *so* much fun if this proposal ever goes live:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1269/english-language-usage?referrer=ZzO7k8xMx5E1

Comment: @jaydles: there are benefits to remaining amongst amateurs. :D

Answer (score 7):

> Oh.. there's a moment... coming. There's a moment coming, it's... it's not here yet. It's on the way... It's still in the future. Here... here it is! (a beat) Oh.. it's gone, man. There's no present, man. Everything is the near future and the recent past.
>
> -- George Carlin (1937 - 2008)

If we allow these questions, we're begging for what are essentially duplicates later on, when the next generation comes out. These questions by definition get outdated, and trying to revive them later is frankly ineffective.

With the ever-advancing state-of-the-art, these questions (to me) should be treated the way Super User tries to treat shopping questions (as that is what they are): Shut 'em down. They'll eventually be just noise.

Comment: They're not just shut down on SU. They're shut down with a vengeance.